# Add UILabel to view objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I would like to add a label for each bracket made. I am getting "Reciever type 'draw 2D' (my class) for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'addSubView'" for the second to last line. And I am getting "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'" for the last line.

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGFloat bracketStartX = 50;
    CGFloat bracketEndX = 200;
    CGFloat bracketStartY = 25  + (i * height / 4);
    CGFloat bracketEndY = 80 + (i * height / 4);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bracketStartX, bracketStartY);

    //make bracket
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bracketEndX, bracketStartY);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bracketEndX, bracketEndY);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bracketStartX, bracketEndY);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bracketEndX, (bracketEndY + bracketStartY)/2 );
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bracketEndX + 50, (bracketEndY + bracketStartY)/2);

    UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(bracketStartX + 5, bracketStartY - 5, 20, 15)];
    label.text = @"text"; //etc...
    [self addSubView:label];
    [label release];

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[self addSubview]; // lowercase v`

If you're using ARC, do not `release` your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your class is not a subclass of UIView which is why you cannot call addSubView. Also since you are using ARC you can safely remove the release call, ARC will dispose of that for you.